# Difference between turns to and turned into

Tags: word-choice, prepositional-phrases

What is the difference between between turns to and turns into. Are they same and can be used alternatively. For example

- *He turns to a recluse during his exam time.*
- *Suddenly his pleasant dream turned into a nightmare.*
- *Roads were turned to mud by days of rain.*

Especially, in the third sentence it seems like both turned to and turned into are suitable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Turn *to*", when referring to a person, is *normally* used to mean either that you have literally rotated to face something, or figuratively that you have looked to someone or something for advice, eg:

> He turned to face his friend.
>   He turned to religion when his parents died.

I think "turn to" has been incorrectly used in your first example. "*He turns to a recluse during his exam time*" would literally mean that he looked to a recluse for help or advice with his exams. If the intended meaning is that he shuts himself away to study, I think it should really be "he turns into a recluse".

---

"Turn *to*" *can* be used to denote change in some contexts though eg:

> When spring turns to summer, temperatures rise.
>   When it rains, the field turns to mud.

You just have to be careful that you don't use it in an ambiguous way, for example:

> After a few miles, this road turns into mud.

This could mean either that the road *becomes* a mud track after a few miles, or that there is a bend in the road which literally *turns* into some mud.

---

"Turn *into*" usually means to change from one thing *into* another, eg:

> Bruce Banner turns into the Hulk.
>   Our holiday turned into a nightmare.

But again, as the past tense of "turn" it could be used directionally:

> I saw your house as soon as I turned into your road.

Context, as always, is very important and dictates the meaning.

---

Your second and third examples are quite clear:

> Suddenly his pleasant dream turned into a nightmare.

This clearly means one thing (dream) changed into another (nightmare).

> Roads were turned to mud by days of rain.

This is clear that the roads were changed as the context does not allow for the directional meaning of a road turning.

Comment: @SudhirSharma Updated.